# How to pause the Win32_printJob by Printername and JobID

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, print-spooler-api, printqueue

**TASK**

> When user print the document ,pause the pop will appear then fill the form  click enter the form will closed and  job has been resumed.
>
> We have  **50 Network Printers** , **2000 Client Machine** and **one print server**.
>
> EACH CLIENT had **3 or 4 printers**

**PROBLEM**

> If user print the document locally **(EX:PDF PRINTER, XPS DOCUMENT WRITER)** (or) using network printer **(CANON,HP)** the print-job was immediately PAUSE.

**MY TRIES**

When print any of the document the event listener watching and return the **print job**.

- In **First Pause Method** sometimes work and mostof time doesn't work properly.Because, Its searching for the printjob but its not there is already printed.
- In **Second Pause Method** doesn't work Because,event listener return the Managementbaseobject but If want to pause the Print Job  need ManagementObject  **How to convert ManageBaseObject to  ManageObject**

> PRINTJOB EVENT LISTENER CODE

```
    managementEvent = new ManagementEventWatcher();
    managementEvent.Query = new EventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 0.1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'");
    managementEvent.Scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
    managementEvent.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(printJobArrived_EventArrived);
    managementEvent.Start();
```

> MAIN ACTION CODE

```
private void printJobArrived_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
  try
     {
CurrentprintJob = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

                       }
}
```

> TO PAUSE THE PRINTJOB METHOD 1

```
 public bool PausePrintJob(string jobname)
            {
                bool isActionPerformed = false;
                try
                { 
                    string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob WHERE Name LIKE '%"+jobname+"%'";

                    ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrintJobs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery);
                    ManagementObjectCollection prntJobCollection = searchPrintJobs.Get();
                    foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection)
                    {
                                prntJob.InvokeMethod("Pause", null);
                                isActionPerformed = true;
                   }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    new LogFile().WriteErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                }
                return isActionPerformed;
            }
```

> TO PAUSE THE PRINTJOB METHOD 2

```
 public bool PausePrintJob(ManagementObject currentPrintJob, bool makePause)
        {
            bool isActionPerformed = false;
            try
            {
                {
                    if (makePause == true && currentPrintJob != null)
                    {
                        currentPrintJob.InvokeMethod("Pause", null);
                        isActionPerformed = true;
                    }
                    else if (makePause == true && currentPrintJob != null)
                    {
                        currentPrintJob.InvokeMethod("Resume", null);
                        isActionPerformed = false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new LogFile().WriteErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);

            }
            return isActionPerformed;
        }
```

Comment: That's a ridiculous amount of code to accomplish a simple thing. Nick Westgate's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 3):

WMI is too slow for this. You probably need to use [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162722(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FindNextPrinterChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162723(v=vs.85).aspx).

You might find [these](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14690/Printers-and-SafeHandles) [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15084/Printers-and-SafeHandles-Part) [useful](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74359/Ask-for-and-receive-change-notifications-from-a-pr).

Comment: We have 50 network printers and 200 clients (means user) and one print server..... The  client machine   printing with in the any  network printer.. how to monitoring the 50 machine  at the time when  client click to print...

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you. If the print is not through the print server you need your software on the client. If on the server you need to monitor multiple printers. The second example link I gave you covers this. It has a Threadpool thread waiting on each notification handle. The other way you can do it is to have an array of notification handles and wait on all of them.

Comment: Ya i saw the example link.. but they do pause the printer then resume the printer....that's only confused... Suppose first user already use the printer and  the second user want to use the same printer... Ok... Will read again... @Nick.am very beginner in Windows application...so.. i stucked everywhere

Comment: Pausing a printer or a job is different. Pausing a printer will print no jobs. Pausing a job will stop that job; other jobs will print. If you are a beginner then this is a lot to learn. It won't be easy. Maybe you can use some third-party software to accomplish your goal. Google "windows print management software".

Comment: Thanks... I have an another doubt .. all the printers are shared ,,i just call monitoring via  NOTITICATION  return 5digit job id and the original printer create the (0-255) job id. I tried the findfirstprinterchangenotification but they returned the 5 digit job id only... How to get the original job id from client system. In WMI return the 2 job (5digit and 3 digit) also..

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you can't get this from the server. Maybe only on the client. If you pause the job can you still use WMI to get that? And do you still need it?

Comment: Oh, Thanks. Now, am move my `Print Queue Monitor` code to server. am stuck  again on `WIN32_Methods`. In Spooler API  to get PrintJob Data using `EnumJobs` but i cant to get that how to  get the `JobInfo , JOBINFO1, JOBINFO2` using any other methods or can you share any samples using ENUMJOBS ..Please Suggest me. @Nick Westgate

Comment: If I have answered your original question please accept the answer. This sounds like a new question.

Comment: Actually i can't to pause the printjob using find next printer change notification and findfirstprinterchangenotification.. am using these then get the job id and pause the printjob using set job. But it doesn't working.. printjob some time paused but again i try to resume.. its can't to resume again.. automatically. Deleted.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSekar Accept the answer and upvote it already. Your reluctance to do that one simple thing is why people quit answering questions here.

Comment: @CareyGregory Sorry.. I Accept this answer. and My problem also solved I can't to ask any new question.. that's only i delete this question

Comment: @KarthikeyanSekar You apparently don't understand how to accept an answer. See the check mark under the vote total on this question? Click it. Then click the up arrow to upvote the question. There is no need to delete anything.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I've found a solution on MSDN official documentation website for controlling printer, here is the link:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6592/A-Simple-Approach-for-Controlling-Print-Jobs-using

It shows that how to `Pause`, `Resume` and `Delete` a print job. The core class is `Win32_PrintJob`.
The variable of `printJob` is from `ManagementObjectSearcher` object which searched one printer instance.

```
printJob.InvokeMethod("Pause", null);
printJob.InvokeMethod("Resume", null);
printJob.Delete()
```

I still found that its Python implementation of code : 
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#watch-for-new-print-jobs

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

print_job_watcher = c.Win32_PrintJob.watch_for (
  notification_type="Creation",
  delay_secs=1
)

while 1:
  pj = print_job_watcher ()
  print "User %s has submitted %d pages to printer %s" % \
    (pj.Owner, pj.TotalPages, pj.Name)
```