# How to programmatically achieve editing of the spool file header of the normal windows print queue 'spool file' before it is sent to the printer?

Tags: java, c#, printing, print-spooler-api, pjl

How to intercept and change the windows 7 print spool file (.SPL) to add some additional information in the header like '@PJL SET NAME="PainPoint" ' before this file is sent to the printer during the execution of the print job?

The .SPL file partial extract from top is :

```
%-12345X@PJL SET STRINGCODESET=UTF8
@PJL COMMENT DATE=02/08/2017
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=PCLXL
) HP-PCL XL;2;1;FXXPL2-1.0.0,WINNT-6.1,XPL2DRV-6.9.1.1
?X???........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the spool file is obviously trivial. The trick is how to get access to the spool file.

I can think of a few ways offhand:

1. Pause the print job after spooling, edit it, then release it. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303965/how-to-pause-the-win32-printjob-by-printername-and-jobid/39411341#39411341). This is not trivial and you may need to resort to third-party software depending on time/effort available.
2. Create a print driver or [spooler component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/print/print-spooler-components) such as a port or [language monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/print/language-monitors) to edit the file. (Thanks to Carey Gregory for the suggestion to use a language monitor). This is a big topic and you'll have to read a lot of documentation to figure out how to do it, but there is a sample (Pjlmon) in the WDK. Note that the newer V4 driver model for Windows 8/Server 2012 [doesn't support these components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/print/v4-driver-connectivity-architecture).
3. If you don't need to do this transparently you could set up [RedMon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/) (free) to call your app to edit the spool file. RedMon will then send it to the desired printer.
4. VeryPDF has some [similar commercial products](http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201607/how-to-capture-printer-spooler-file-when-printing-and-then-view-andor-print-that-spooler-file-again-42708.html) with more capabilities.

Comment: Well I am a java/scala background, what do you suggest? The actual task is to include additional PJL headers to the spool file and then send to the printer.

Comment: Since you imply you want to avoid native coding, I would suggest trying option 3 first.

Comment: I setup RedMon but it works to forward to another printer/output only. 

I think I would work on Visual C++ or sth else, is it absolutely achievable to pause a print job after spooling, edit it and then release? I need to do achieve this functionality for only 1 printer but not on other printers which are working normally.

Comment: There are other port monitors that I think you could use, but they are commercial. VeryPDF have one amongst their many products - it's [mentioned here](http://www.verydoc.com/blog/intercepting-data-sent-to-a-windows-printer.html). Another one [is here](http://www.alphatronics.net/AVPMon.html). Or you could write your own port monitor (option 2) using the Windows SDK monitor sample as a base, or perhaps the RedMon source. But yes, option 1 is definitely possible. [Here is some software](http://www.papercut.com/products/free-software/) that uses this technique - my other answer links to samples.

Comment: This is what language monitors are for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/print/language-monitors

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thanks. Why don't you expand that into an answer? ; - )

Comment: Eh, not enough time. Why don't you just add a note about it in your answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Done. But I remembered that monitors aren't supported for V4 drivers. Also, I'm not sure how to add a language monitor to an existing printer.

Comment: Heh, yeah, I didn't want to have to explain the v4 stuff, installation, etc. I think merely pointing out the option is sufficient because it is a lot of work just to understand these components and get them working.