# Capture printer job data stream - Windows

Tags: c#, windows, printing, print-spooler-api

I will be working with a mix of networked and local printers and need to capture the actual data sent for printing going to either local or networked printers.

I have looked over the print spooler api and some of it looks promising, but it seems like it would require acquiring jobID and finding the corresponding file (if you enable save to file for printing).

I have also seen an application called redmon that could work for my purposes but I was hoping to write a unique c# application to acquire the data and handle it.

My Goal: gather print data sent from an application I have no access to. I will then need to work with this data and possibly store it for later use. I obviously would prefer gathering this through print spooler api calls but it seems like this isn't functionality built into it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Here's an answer you might find relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102898/how-to-programmatically-achieve-editing-of-the-spool-file-header-of-the-normal-w/42124626#42124626). There are a few similar questions on SO if you look around. Unfortunately the print API doesn't make this particularly easy.

Comment: Doing this in C# is mainly going to make your life harder. Also, be aware that RedMon and similar solutions involving port monitors won't work with v4 print drivers. So yeah, this is a big complicated project you've got.